# Java: not able to get value

Tags: java

Constants class:

```
public class Constants { 
    FileHandle h = new FileHandle();
    String[] LIST_DATA3 = h.getA().split(Pattern.quote("."));
    public static  int NEW_ELEMENT_ID =0;
}
```

FileHandle class:

```
public class FileHandle {

   String a;
   String b;
   String c;
   String d;

  public void openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {        
    File dir = new File("DB");
    if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
    }
   // System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
                if (s.hasNext()) {
                    this.a = (a == null) ? s.next() :a + "."+s.next();                        
                    b = (b == null) ? s.next() :b + "." + s.next();
                    c = (c == null) ? s.next() :c + "." + s.next();
                    d = (d == null) ? s.next() :d + "." + s.next();

                }else{
                s.close();
                }
            }  
        }System.out.println(a); 

    }
  }
  public String getA(){
      if(this.a !=null){
      System.out.println(this.a);
      }

   return this.a;
}
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at databasesearch.Constants.<init>(Constants.java:16)
at databasesearch.Frame.CreatingGUI(Frame.java:63)
at databasesearch.DatabaseSearch.main(DatabaseSearch.java:23)
C:\Users\D1sturbance\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Frame 63 line :

```
    SwingJList<String> myJList = new SwingJList<>(Arrays.asList(con.LIST_DATA3));
```

My problem (in my opinion, tell me if i am wrong): getting NPE because Constants is assuming getA() returns non-null - it's not even calling openFile(), so it's always going to be null in this case. How can i fix it ?

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be loaded the way you're trying to load it...

Comment: So could you please teach me, and tell me my mistake ?

Comment: Don't try to store this in a constants file; do all this loading in an instance, not in static state, and pass that instance around.

Comment: Maybe you can post your answer, it is a little confusing

Comment: You telling me to delete Constants class ?

Comment: Yes, or at the very least these fields shouldn't be in it.  None of those are actually constants; they're all mutable or determined at runtime from the filesystem.

Comment: But if i remove it and add somewhere in my FileHandle class, where should i put them? If i put it only in class in willl be static as well, if in method this LIST will be written but never read, and Frame 63 line will call an error for non static context

Comment: I guess: he is telling you to read some basic book / tutorial about object oriented programming to understand what the difference between static and non-static fields is. Side note on code quality: spend more times when naming your classes and variables. A class called Constants should really really contain only **constant** values that do not change after creation. And variable names a,b, c,d are really bad, too. The name of the variable tells the reader what the variable is used for. a, b,c ... say nothing (except for: give us better names!)

Comment: @user5568235 I'm not telling you to put it in the `FileHandle` class; I'm telling you to, say, have your main method load that data and then pass it around wherever it's needed, possibly stored in a object you create in your `main` method.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get it.  What main method and class you are talking about ?

Comment: @user5568235 From your stack trace it certainly appears that `DatabaseSearch` contains your main method?

Comment: Yes there i declared FileHandle h = new FileHandle();
     h.openFile();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DatabaseSearch class write this:

```
String aaaa;
public DatabaseSearch(){

FileHandle h = new FileHandle();
    try {    
        h.openFile();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 pirmas = h.a;
 System.out.println(pirmas+"cia");
}
```